# Access s3 bucket from Ec2 service

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to AWS and was looking for a bucket policy to enable my ec2 servers access to the S3 buckets on the same account.
I tried using this policy which enables the account:
{
            "Sid": "AddCannedAcl",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account-number:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
But I got access denied on the ec2.

I've found this:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Principal
"Principal": {
  "Service": [
    "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "datapipeline.amazonaws.com" 
  ]
}
Which supposed to enable specifically the ec2. But when editing the policy I get 
"We encountered an internal error. Please try again."
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can create a new IAM user. provide that user what ever permission you like to give on s3. Then copy the security credentials of that user in ~/.aws/config file or ~/.boto file in your ec2 machine. Then you can access s3 using aws-cli or boto python.

Answer (score 0):

Set the bucket policy on the s3 bucket that you want to use, either create a role or use your existing ec2 role to add to the policy.

```
{
    "Version" : "2008-10-17",
    "Statement" : [{
            "Sid" : "",
            "Effect" : "Allow",
            "Principal" : {
                "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/some_role"
            },
            "Action" : [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource" : "arn:aws:s3:::some-s3-bucket/*"
        }, {
            "Sid" : "",
            "Effect" : "Allow",
            "Principal" : {
                "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/some_role"
            },
            "Action" : "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource" : "arn:aws:s3:::some-s3-bucket"
        }
    ]
}
```